# Opening a url from another url using Intent?

Tags: android, url, android-intent

I want to open a url of an image from another url of an image using intent.I am new to android so this code of mine not working.

```
 url_1 = new URL("http://garooh.905pm.com"+com.org.constant.Helper.Gadd_list.get(0).thisEvent.getImage_four_thumb());

 url_2 = new URL("http://garooh.905pm.com"+ com.org.constant.Helper.Gadd_list.get(0).thisEvent.getImage_four_thumb());
    Intent intent = new Intent();
    intent.setAction(Intent.ACTION_VIEW);
    intent.setDataAndType(url_1, url_2);
    startActivity(intent);
```

Comment: Where are you displaying this initial url? in a webview? or is it a clickable button in your app? Try [this](http://developer.android.com/training/basics/firstapp/starting-activity.html)

Comment: basically i am setting a clicklistener on an image.

Answer (score 0):

Am i right in thinking you have an imagebutton and when you click it you want to go to 1 of those URLs?

Try adding this to your imageButton.

```
imageButton.setOnClickListener(new locatorButtonClickListener());

private class imageButtonListener implements OnClickListener 
{
    @Override
    public void onClick(View button) {
        new DisplayImageFromUrl((ImageButton) findViewById(R.id.imageButtonEnd), this).execute(//Enter your link here);
}
```

**UPDATE**
Try using this Async task

```
    //Display image to bitmap using URL
public class DisplayImageFromUrl extends AsyncTask<String, Void, Bitmap> {
    ImageView bmImage;
    Context context1;
    ProgressDialog pd;
    @Override
    protected void onPreExecute() {
        super.onPreExecute();
        pd = new ProgressDialog(context1);
        pd.setMessage("Loading Images...");
        pd.show();
    }
    public DisplayImageFromUrl(ImageView bmImage, Context context) {
        this.bmImage = bmImage;
        this.context1 = context;
    }
    protected Bitmap doInBackground(String... urls) {
        String urldisplay = urls[0];
        Bitmap mIcon11 = null;
        try {
            InputStream in = new java.net.URL(urldisplay).openStream();
            mIcon11 = BitmapFactory.decodeStream(in);
        } catch (Exception e) {
            Log.e("Error", e.getMessage());
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        return mIcon11;
    }
    protected void onPostExecute(Bitmap result) {
        bmImage.setImageBitmap(result);
        pd.dismiss();
    }
}
```

and you call it like this in your activity.

```
        new DisplayImageFromUrl((ImageButton) findViewById(R.id.imageButtonEnd), this).execute(//Enter your link here);
```

Comment: i have a smaller image on my first screen, when i click it will show me a bigger image on same screen.And i have both paths for images.

Comment: First you have to download the url image to be able to display it on an imagebutton. I edited my answer to include an async task that you could use to place a url image to an imagebutton.